# Entanglement of formation of the mixture of maximally entangled states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

Suppose we have two spin-$S$ systems. Let $\left| \psi_{a,b} \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| a,b \right\rangle+\left| b,a \right\rangle)$ be the maximally entangled state. ($a\neq b$ and $-S\leq a,b \leq S$.)

What is the [Entanglement of formation](https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/entanglement-formation) for $\rho=\frac{1}{C} \sum_{a\neq b} \left| \psi_{a,b} \right\rangle \left\langle \psi_{a,b} \right|$? $C$ is the normalizing constant.

A trivial upper bound is 1. But can we give a nontrivial upper bound or even calculate it explicitly?

Comment: If I understand correctly, your states are a subset of Bell-diagonal for qubit-qubit states. The entanglement of formation of these states is known exactly, see: https://www.quantiki.org/wiki/bell-diagonal-state

Comment: Why do you call these "maximally entangled"?  They are not, except for qubits.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough For qubits, $\rho$ is pure.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Just to clarify, suppose $S=1$. Then $a,b$ can take values from $\{-1,0,1\}$. I want to know the entanglement of formation of the mixture of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0,1 \right\rangle+\left| 1,0 \right\rangle)$, $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 0,2 \right\rangle+\left| 2,0 \right\rangle)$, and $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\left| 1,2 \right\rangle+\left| 2,1 \right\rangle)$. I am not sure how to name these states properly.

Comment: @KennethGoodenough See my previous comment for clarification.

Comment: I am not sure either, but they are not "maximally entangled".

Comment: Is there a special reason that you are interested in those? Do they have some special properties? That might be useful.

Comment: If you include for a=b, these should be Werner states with EoF 0.  Maybe one can use some twirling to Werner states to also compute the EoF of these.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I deliberately exclude the case for $a=b$. I expect $\rho$ is "less entangled" than a Bell state, so I want to find an entanglement measure to separate them. Any entanglement measure other than EoF is also desirable.

Comment: But why do you exclude that case - any specific motivation?

Comment: To start with, your state has a non-positive partial transpose, so it is for sure entangled.

Comment: Next, you can set up a protocol which allows to distill entanglement by letting both A and B project onto either subspace spanned by any two states |a> and |b>.  If they obtain the same result - which happens with finite probability - they have a maximally entangled qubit state.

Comment: Note that you can for sure compute the negativity, if that measure if good enough!

Comment: [This paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/quant-ph/0010095.pdf) may be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say that any other entanglement measure is fine, let's compute the negativity.  Let me denote by $\rho_{ab}:=|\psi_{a,b}\rangle\langle\psi_{a,b}|$.

With $^{T_A}$ the partial transpose, we have
$$
\rho_{ab}^{T_A} = \frac12 \Big[
|a,a\rangle\langle b,b|+|b,b\rangle\langle a,a|+
|a,b\rangle\langle a,b|+|b,a\rangle\langle b,a|\Big]\ .
$$
Thus (denoting by $D:=2S+1$ the number of basis states),
$$
\rho^{T_A} = \frac{2}{D(D-1)}\sum_{a>b} \rho_{ab}^{T_A}
$$
is block-diagonal with two blocks: $\rho^{T_A}_{ab,a'b'}$ for $a\ne b$, $a'\ne b'$ is diagonal with entries $\tfrac{1}{D(D-1)}$ (i.e., $D(D-1)$ entries), and  $\rho^{T_A}_{aa,a'a'}$ (a $D\times D$ matrix) equals $\tfrac{1}{D(D-1)}$ everywhere except on the diagonal (which is zero). Since the latter equals 
$$
\tfrac{D}{D(D-1)}|+\rangle\langle +|-\tfrac{1}{D(D-1)}1\!\!1\ ,
$$
with $|+\rangle = (\sum |a\rangle)/\sqrt{D}$, it has eigenvalues $-\tfrac{1}{D(D-1)}$ with multiplicity $D-1$ and $\tfrac{1}{D}$ with multiplicity $1$, respectively.

The sum of the absolute value of the eigenvalues of $\rho^{T_A}$ is thus
$$
\|\rho^{T_A}\|_1={D(D-1)}\frac{1}{D(D-1)}+(D-1)\frac{1}{D(D-1)}+\frac{1}{D} = 
1+\frac{2}{D}\ .
$$
The negativity is thus
$$
\mathcal N(\rho) = \frac{\|\rho^{T_A}\|_1-1}{2} = \frac{1}{D}
$$
and the log-negativity
$$
E_N(\rho) = \log(\|\rho^{T_A}\|_1) = \log(1+2/D)\ .
$$

Comment: Thank you, Norbert. Another question. We know logarithmic negativity isn't a **faithful** entanglement measure. Is $\rho$ necessarily close to a separable state for large D? If so, we can treat $\rho$ as if it were a separable state.

Comment: @user193108 "Close" in which sense? That might be relevant for the distance measure.

Comment: In trace norm. What concerns me is that $\rho$ may be still far from separable in the trace norm even $E_N(\rho) \to 0$.

Comment: Well, I would say the given state **is** far from separable in trace norm (relates to the distillation protocol I mention above).  But this would be a separate question.  (Not to mention that these kind of questions cause lot of work and seem to give zero votes.) --- But why don't you ask what you are **actually** interested in?

Comment: @user193108 Then I would suggest you ask your **actual** question (i.e. separating $\rho$ from the Bell state -- BTW, what does that even mean, they live in different Hilbert spaces!), and if you want, you can subsequently give your thoughts which relate it to other question.  This way, you ask a question which is probably *much* harder than what you actually want to know!